# How to append items to ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, append, field

I've got a function to create syllables for words.

I use it like this: `syllables(word1field);` - creates List with syllables: `aa,bb,cc`

and `syllables(word2field);` - creates List with syllables: `dd,ee,ff`

And in the result I get `dd,ee,ff`, but I need `aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff`.

Is there possibility to append second list to first?

Comment: `firstList.addAll(secondList);`

Comment: Yeah, but this list has the same name, it's included in the function. I use only textField name to execute it.

Comment: Could you show the code for you syllables method

Comment: This method is very long, but the part that I talk about is: `List<String> sStart = new ArrayList<String>();

String ss="";

for(int f=0; f<syllables3.size(); f++){
   ss = syllables3.get(f);
   
   if(f==0){
        sStart.add(sz);
   }
 .
 .
 .
}` I want to append it in if loop. I don't now if it's helpful in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `dd,ee,ff` because when you call the same method again, it overrides the first `ArrayList` that is created.

The best thing you could do, that I can think of, is to make your `ArrayList` global because currently you just keep getting rid of the previous values and create a new `ArrayList` with the new values you give it. Try doing something like:

```
public class MyClass {

    private List<String> myArray;

    public MyClass() {
        myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void syllables(wordfield) {
        // do whatever you need to with wordfield
        myArray.add(syllable);
    }
```

I don't know how you've got everything laid out but this is the best solution I can think of.